# Converting a Double to a String produces Optional

Tags: swift

I am retrieving a rating from a database and need to set the value to a view as a Double and a label as a String. I can't seem to convert the Double to a String.  The label and the printed string in the debug area both read - Optional(3.0)

```
if let myRating = Double(myString) {
    self.newRating = self.rounded(myRating, toNearest:0.25)
    self.ratingView.rating = self.newRating!
    let stringValue = String(describing: self.newRating)
    self.ratingLabel.text = stringValue
    print("My rating label is: \(self.ratingLabel.text)")
}
```

Comment: Why not just unwrap the optional after?

Comment: It's strange it says I can't force unwrap non optional string.  I tried that here:let stringValue = String(describing: self.newRating)!

Comment: Your stringValue is a String (non optional) but self.ratingLabel.text is an optional.

Comment: I was able to solve this using the following statement:
let stringValue = String(format:"%.2f", self.newRating!)

Comment: @MartinMuldoon THere's no point to be force unwrapping like that, if you can just extract out the non-optional expression and use it directly. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if let myRating = Double(myString) {
    self.newRating = self.rounded(myRating, toNearest:0.25)
    self.ratingView.rating = self.newRating!
    let stringValue = String(describing: self.newRating)
    self.ratingLabel.text = stringValue
    print("My rating label is: \(self.ratingLabel.text)")
}
```

Several issues here:

1. `self.newRating` is an optional. You assign `self.rounded(myRating, toNearest:0.25)` to it, which makes it non-nil, but you're still forced to force unwrap it when you try to use it. Instead, extract out the expression value to a non-optional local variable:

   ```
   if let myRating = Double(myString) {
       let roundedRating = self.rounded(myRating, toNearest:0.25)
       self.newRating = roundedRating
       self.ratingView.rating = roundedRating

       let stringValue = String(roundedRating)
       self.ratingLabel.text = stringValue
       print("My rating label is: \(self.ratingLabel.text)")
   }
   ```
2. Because `self.newRating` was a `Double?`, it couldn't be used with the regular String initializer that creates a `String` from a `Double`. The IDE complained about this, and proposed that you use `String(describing:)` instead. `String(describing:)` would have the following, undesirable effect:

   - A `Double?` variable with a value of `1.23` would be converted into `"Optional(1.23)"`.
   - A `Double?` variable that's nil would be converted into `"nil"`

   Considering the `nil` case isn't possible (since you had just assigned `self.rounded(myRating, toNearest:0.25)` to `self.newRating`), and the `Optional(...)` part of the String is undesirable, this is *not* what you want to be using.

   Now that we have `roundedRating`, a non-optional `Double`, we can call the regular initializer of `String`, which behaves as you desire.
3. In a similar fashion to #2, the String interpolation (`\(...)`) of `self.ratingLabel.text` will either yield `Optional("some text")` or `nil`, since the `text` property of `UILabel` is optional. This is probably not what you're going for. You can use the `roundedRating` local variable directly, since it has a non-optional value.

   ```
   if let myRating = Double(myString) {
       let roundedRating = self.rounded(myRating, toNearest:0.25)
       self.newRating = roundedRating
       self.ratingView.rating = roundedRating

       let stringValue = String(roundedRating)
       self.ratingLabel.text = stringValue
       print("My rating label is: \(roundedRating)")
   }
   ```
4. Now that `stringValue` is only used in one place, and since it doesn't offer any descriptive information (we can see that it's a string, and obviously it's a value), we should just inline it to simplify the code:

   ```
   if let myRating = Double(myString) {
       let roundedRating = self.rounded(myRating, toNearest:0.25)
       self.newRating = roundedRating
       self.ratingView.rating = roundedRating

       self.ratingLabel.text = String(roundedRating)
       print("My rating label is: \(roundedRating)")
   }
   ```
5. Why does `self.newRating` exist, if it's only ever going to mirror that value of `self.ratingView.rating`? This introduces potential for bugs, stemming from accidentally making a change to one, without remembering to mirror the change in the other. Either make `newRating` a computed property whose value derives from `self.ratingView.rating`, or remove it completely and only use `self.ratingView.rating`.

Comment: Hi @Alexander,     I have an optional double var price: Double?
The label is supposed to print the price but simulator shows nil. 
        priceLabel.text = "\(meal.price)"

Comment: Well, your price is `nil`... what's your question?

Comment: There's a price in the database,  price = json["price"].double 
How can it be nil?

Comment: Line error in priceLabel.text = "(meal.price)" --- Error: "String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit?"

Comment: @ConsBulaquena Well I have no idea what JSON library you're using (or why you're even using a JSON library, in Swift 4, when Codable is the way to go), so I don't have much to go by. Most likely, `double` is a computed property that returns `Double?`, so that it can return `nil` in the case that the value for the given key either doesn't exist, or exists but isn't a `Double`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm using SwiftyJSON, Firebase backend.